# Як перекласти з російської слово "поделка"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як перекласти з російської слово "поделка"? Цікавить значення як неякісний виріб, адже знайдений мною варіант перекладу "саморобка", на мою думку, не містить негативного забарвлення.

> Это приложение очень неудобно и содержит множество ошибок. Просто какая-то **поделка**.

Comment: Поки спадає на думку лише _[халтура](http://sum.in.ua/s/khaltura)_.

Comment: @Sasha, ми не заохочуємо (напів-)відповіді у коментарях. Якщо запитання є повним і зрозумілим, варто написати повноцінну відповідь. Якщо ж, на вашу думку, запитання є half-baked, йому бракує продемонстрованої спроби автора самостійно знайти відповідь на запитання, та/або ви не упевнені у тому, що ваш запропонований варіант відповідає авторському перекладові іноземного слова власними словами, то про це треба написати авторові і проголосувати за закриття запитання.

Comment: якщо "саморобка" не містить неґативного забарвлення, то й "поделка" також його не містить, бо у реченні саме на цьому й акцентується, що щось саморобне, а не професійно зроблене.

Comment: @P.Vowk, я б не був таким упевненим. Цілком може бути, що слова в різних мовах, у яких однакове основне значення, мають різні конотації. Так й навіть якщо автор неправий у цьому (припустімо, він переоцінює ступінь негативності слова _поделка_ й недооцінює можливості вжитку слова _саморобка_), питання все одно лишається актуальним: що вжити замість _саморобка_, щоб посилити негативні конотації?

Comment: @P.Vowk *самоделка* і *поделка* можуть мати різні значення. Про негативний контекст *поделки* свідчать російські словники.

Comment: Не скажу, що у мене прямо глибоке відчуття російської (все ж таки не зовсім рідна), але у приведеному вами прикладі слово "поделка" виглядає як не зовсім на своєму місці. А намагатися дати влучний переклад кострубатому оригіналу — завдання, м'яко кажучи, невдячне.

Answer (score 3):

Неякісний, примітивний виріб, виготовлений власноруч, нашвидкуруч, не-фахівцями, без дотримання технології, техніки безпеки, організації праці — це [*кустарщина*](http://sum.in.ua/s/kustarshhyna) або [*кустарництво*](http://sum.in.ua/s/kustarnyctvo).

> ***КУСТА́РНИЦТВО***, а, сер.
> 2. перен. Робота, що ведеться неорганізовано, примітивно.

> ***КУСТА́РЩИНА***, и, жін., розм. Те саме, що кустарництво.
>
> - — Так от, виступає, значить, інженер і зводить до того, що держава дає передову техніку, але на цю техніку, мовляв, в наших МТС налипла кустарщина і відсталість (Семен Журахович, Вечір.., 1958, 22);
> - — Це кустарщина, а не сад.. Це треба ставити на державні рейки. Зрозуміло? Ось добув для вас [І. В. Мічуріна] субсидію..! (Олександр Довженко, I, 1958, 457);
> - У забудові села великої шкоди завдає кустарщина. Хто де облюбував місце, там і будується (Літературна Україна, 3.IX 1965, 4).

Answer (score 2):

Розмовний варіант у моєму вжитку - "Поробка". В творах письменників воно також зустрічається, наприклад у [Андрій Химко "У пазурах вампіра. I. Шляхами до прийднів", 1957](https://prostolib.com/books/442141):

> Продав дрова, всякі **поробки**: ложки, люльки, ярма, снізки, іншу марницю, купив шкіру волячу, конячу і трохи козиної та овечої та й спробував промислу.

Comment: Дякую, що доповнили!